# jQuery - Join jQuery Objects, equivalent to Multiple Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

**I have this:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
   var var1 = $('selector1').find('iframe').contents().find('body').find('selector2')
   var var2 = $('selector3');
   // Some function
   }); //end
```

**I can do this:** (somefunction() doesn't exists as a function, it could be any function)

```
$(var1).somefunction(someattributes);
$(var2).somefunction(someattributes);
```

**But I want to do something like this:** (jointhisselectorwith() doesn't exists as a function, it's what I want)

```
$(var1).jointhisselectorwith(var2).somefunction(someattributes);
```

**It's possible to join jQuery objects? Thanks!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add).

If `var1` and `var2` contain selectors:

```
$(var1).add(var2).somefunction(someattributes);
```

Or it also works with jQuery instances (which is what you have, you didn't need the `$(var1)` bit at all):

```
var j1 = $(var1);
var j2 = $(var2);
j1.add(j2).somefunction(someattributes);
```

Gratuitous live example:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var var1 = ".foo";
  var var2 = ".bar";
  $(var1).add(var2).css("color", "green");
  setTimeout(function() {
    var j1 = $(".foo");
    var j2 = $(".bar");
    j1.add(j2).css("color", "blue");
  }, 500);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">I'm foo</div>
<div class="bar">I'm bar</div>
<div class="foo">I'm foo</div>
<div class="bar">I'm bar</div>
<div class="foo">I'm foo</div>
<div class="bar">I'm bar</div>
```